# Sylius : Could not load type "app.form.type.slider"

Tags: sylius, symfony-2.8

the form type service can't be defined , where is the problem!!!

**AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml:**

```
app_slider_create:
path: /sliders/slider/new
methods: [GET, POST]
defaults:
    _controller: app.controller.slider:createAction
    _sylius:
        form: app.form.type.slider
```

**AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml:**

```
app.form.type.slider:
    class: AppBundle\Form\Type\add_img_sliderType
    tags:
                - { name: form.type, alias: app_slider }
    arguments: [@doctrine, @sylius.context.locale]
```

**AppBundle/Form/Type/add_img_sliderType.php:**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Form\Type\AbstractResourceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;

class add_img_sliderType extends AbstractResourceType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Build your custom form!
       $builder
       ->add('lib', 'text', [
      'label' => 'Libélle',
      ])
      ->add('description', 'text', [
     'label' => 'Description',
      ])
     ->add('path',FileType::class, [
    'required' => true,
    'label' => 'Photo',
    ])
    ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_slider';
    }


}
```

Comment: @Brett i edited my code so you can see the sliderType

Comment: And it's definitely loading the services.yml file? Add the code for your DependencyInjection/*Extension.php file too

Comment: Or add a syntax error in the yml file and try and load a page. If it loads, then it's not actually loading the yml file. If it breaks, that means it is

Comment: @Brett i've added a syntax error in the yaml file  ,and its actually shows an exception when i load a page

Comment: @Bret thx for reading my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you should define form in routing by tag, not by full form name. So your routing configuration should be:

```
app_slider_create:
    path: /sliders/slider/new
    methods: [GET, POST]
    defaults:
        _controller: app.controller.slider:createAction
        _sylius:
            form: app_slider
```

Please, let me know if it helps ;)

Comment: i've tried your solution and an other exception appeared : 
Unable to find template "/create.html.twig" (looked into: C:\wamp3\www\sidratsoft_wss\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form, C:\wamp3\www\sidratsoft_wss\vendor\knplabs\knp-menu\src\Knp\Menu/Resources/views). what can be the problem ?

Comment: You should define template under `_sylius`->`template` key, `/create.html.twig` is the default value. For more info, please check out [SyliusResourceBundle docs](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/), you should find there any answers for all questions ;)
BTW - I see you're working on **Windows**, so please, be aware that **Sylius** support for this OS is still WIP and you can encounter some difficulties.

Comment: thx ,that' it , i missed the template key .
excuse me for disturbing you , but can you tell me how can i upload files to my project from that formtype to display them later  , what should i do  to achieve that?

Comment: It's strictly Symfony case, so I think you should base on official **Symfony2** documentation (which is pretty good, btw) - especially [this section](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html). Good luck!

Comment: i thought that sylius may have a special way to do that through a bundle or something